# why solidify increase beyound the height

Tags: modifiers

[image]
I have made a normal circle and cut into half. Then with single vertex selected i just pull it out and added the solidify. As u can see my .gif file. After adding the solidify modifier the circle has got the solidify but where the point i pull there its not been perfect solidify it has been increase the height from the circle edges. Its not in the same height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the way the *Soldify* modifier works. It basically adds thickness to faces in the direction of their **normals**. As you can see on the animation below, the face is extruded in the direction of its normal (the cyan line).

[image]